# Looking for a script that will allow me to scroll content sideways

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find some javascript code that I can embed on my website that will allow me to scroll content from left to right or right to left.  This script here:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/scrollc2.htm

Has the basic functionality that I am looking for, but it scrolls content from top to bottom.  I want to be able to scroll my content sideways and have it scroll when I hover over some arrows just like the above mentioned script does.

Does anyone know of anything that will work for me?  Or perhaps it would be simple to modify the above mentioned script to scroll side to side.  Thanks.

Comment: Adapt the script that you're already found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have time to edit it for you but try to change the offsetHeight to offsetWidth and style.top to style.left;